# Rails, how to link to another static page within my domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails, how to link to another static page within my domain.

I have such as: (this is home page.)

```
<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails"), 'www.goole.com' %>
```

instead of link_to google. I want it link to "contact" static page.
What should I put there?

my routes.rb is this:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "users/new"
  # get "static_pages/home"
  # get "static_pages/help"
  # get "static_pages/about"
  # get "static_pages/contact"
  root 'static_pages#home'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails"), contact_path %>`. Run `rake routes` to see named hepler. Read more information at [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails"), {controller: 'static_pages', action: 'contact'} %>
```

See more here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to 'contact', "/contact" %>
```

or use normal html

```
<a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
```

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to